# Cant read my "map" layout from text and put it in the array. app just crashes

Tags: java, android-studio

Hi im trying to make my first Android game and i have a problem with making my Tilemap. I dont have a problem when reading my first two rows but it wont load the grid.(i have already made the game normally, im trying to transfer it to an app so i know the code works but cant seem to make it work on android studio). the app just crashes for some reason
this is the code

```
e public void createTilemap(Context context) {
    BufferedReader reader;

    try {
        final InputStream file = context.getAssets().open("map1.txt");
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        gridWidth = Integer.parseInt(line);
        line = reader.readLine();
        gridHeight = Integer.parseInt(line);

        tileMap = new int[gridHeight][gridWidth];

        String delimiters = " ";

        for(int row = 0; row < gridHeight; row++){
            line = reader.readLine();

            String[] tempStorage = line.split(delimiters);

            for(int col = 0; col < gridWidth; col++){
                line = tempStorage[col];
                int temp = 0;
                temp = Integer.parseInt(line);
                tileMap[row][col] = temp;
            }
            Log.d("this is my deep array", "deep arr: " + Arrays.deepToString(tileMap));
        }


    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

[this is the file im trying to read from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ge6uS.png)

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed IT. Array was wrong size i was asking for 32 and the array was 31 :D